# How to integrate any weather widget in lockscreen apps in WP 8.1?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, lockscreenwidget

I have developed a lockscreen app for window phone 8/8.1, that's released in the windows store, but lot of my friends suggested that I should integrate the weather widgets with customize options like location, refresh interval, etc in the app.

I searched a lot in the internet, I googled a lot, but believe me there seems to be nothing is provided to integrate weather widgets in lockscreen. Is there any way? Or is this something not allowed in WP 8.1?

In windows Phone to work with lockscreen apps, developer have to work with Backgroundtask agent, I know and I did that, but how to access the open area left in the lockscreen?

Any sample code, links or even a guide would do, please help. Please guide me, a novice app developer.

Comment: That's probably because you are using the wrong terms. There is no such thing as "widgets", that's Android terminology. In Windows Phone an app can customize the lock screen by changing the background image or displaying a notification

Comment: Ok, pardon me, but in Windows phone how can I show weather info in lockscreen? There unused space in locckscreen can I customize this using weather, music buttons etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please look in to msdn
[Lock screen for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj571206(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Note this is only for Silverlight applications

Comment: This msdn article about lockscreen is very vague, too little info. Atleast for the developer some sample code is needed.

Comment: This isn't an article, it's the section summary in the documentation. The sections bellow it contain code and samples for each customization type